# Number of ways to arrange great circles on the sphere

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory

I'm reading about the number of arrangement of lines in general position in the plane (see sequence A090338 at OEIS).

Now I would like to consider a similar problem and see in how many ways I can arrange n great circles on the sphere in general positions. (Two arrangement are considered distinct if the corresponding arrangement graphs are different.) Is there a known result for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is at https://oeis.org/A018242 . This result arises from the work in

S. Felsner, F. Hurtado, M. Noy, and I. Streinu, Hamiltonicity and colorings of arrangement graphs, Disc. App. Math. 154 (2000) 2470-2483;

https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.5555/338219.338247

In particular, when n = 5 there is a unique arrangement.